# How do I write to solve the shared folder permission denied Lubuntu 20.04 to Windows 10

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, lubuntu, windows-10

I find many solutions but I don't know enough Linux to understand what to write specifically for my own machine. That is why I wrote the question so specifically because I don't know how to write in Linux.

My shared folder is in (icon that looks like an ipod) `/media/sf_Share`

How do I tell Linux to let me use this folder without getting
`Error Opening directory '/media/sf_Share': Permission Denied` ?

Comment: Could you confirm Win10 is the host OS and Lubuntu is the guest OS, right? Also could you recheck the settings of that virtualbox, shared folders: it should be set as full access (read-only is unchecked).

Comment: Host = Windows ~ To the Terminal: sudo usermod -aG vboxsf e <e = My name I gave to Lubuntu. Dunno what it means but it works.

Comment: It means you added your user to the "vboxsf" group.